# Spring Retry with Transactional Annotation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate, spring-retry

Is the below code the correct way to use  Spring Retry with Transactional?
Or do I need to take care of anything extra ? I am using latest Spring Boot version
Is retry tried after the failed transaction is closed ?

```
@Repository
public class MyRepository {


    @Retryable( value = CustomRetryAbleException.class, maxAttempts = 2, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 30000))
    @Transactional
    Employee updateAndGetEmployee(String date) throw CustomRetryAbleException;
    
    {
         try{
         
        jdbcTemplate.exceute( ....) ; //Call Stored Proc
        }
        
        catch(CustomRetryAbleException c )
        {
          throw  CustomRetryAbleException (" Retry this Exception " );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'This is the way.'

Do not forget to put the @EnableRetry annotation on either your config-class (annotated with @Configuration) or your application-class (annotated with @SpringBootApplication).

Read [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry) for more information.

You can just log something and intentionally make it fail to see if it gets logged again after the delay.

Comment: It appears that Spring wires the advice chain with the retry interceptor first, then the transaction interceptor, so a new transaction is created for each attempt (which is good). If you want to ensure that, you could use 2 beans with the "outer" annotated with `@Retryable` and the "inner` with `@Transactional`.

Comment: @GaryRussell so sample code i have shared is correct ?

Comment: As long as you've done what @H3AR7B3A7 said but, as I said, if you have a retryable bean call the transactional bean, you can be sure that the intercepts will always be in the right order. I would tend to do it that way to, somewhat, separate the concerns.

Comment: @GaryRussell .I think i got you .So you want lets say `m1()` call `updateAndGetEmployee` and annotate `m1` with `@Retryable ` and `updateAndGetEmployee`  annotate with `@Transactional`.Is that correct?

Comment: Right, but they have to be in separate beans, not 2 methods in the same class, that way, the bean with `m1()` gets the retry interceptor and the repo gets the transaction interceptor. As I said, it doesn't seem to be necessary (at least in my test) but I don't know if the order in which the interceptors are added is deterministic, or I just got "lucky", so I prefer to be more explicit so I know for sure the order in which the interceptors are applied.

Comment: @GaryRussell.Yes I  will have `m1()` is another Service class and autowire the `MyRepository`  class